# Retrive select option from database php

Tags: php

The below code show the retrived data from database and it also repeat the same option

For example: if you select employed from dropdown, it repeat the same employed twice in dropdown

```
<select class="txtbox" name="currentstatus">
 <option value="<?php echo "$currentstatus"; ?>"><?php echo "$currentstatus"; ?></option>
 <option value="Employed"<?php if(isset($_POST["currentstatus"]) && $_POST["currentstatus"] == "Employed") echo "selected"; ?>>Employed</option>
 <option value="Unemployed"<?php if(isset($_POST["currentstatus"]) && $_POST["currentstatus"] == "Unemployed") echo "selected"; ?>>Unemployed</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _it repeat the same employed twice in dropdown_ How this happens?

Comment: @Rahil Wazir `<option value="<?php echo "$currentstatus"; ?>"><?php echo "$currentstatus"; ?></option>`     This code retrive from database and the other two options show employed and unemployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? This displays two options and selects one according to the database or by `$_POST`:

```
<select class="txtbox" name="currentstatus">
    <?php foreach (array('Employed', 'Unemployed') as $status): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $status; ?>"<?php if ($currentstatus == $status || (isset($_POST["currentstatus"]) && $_POST["currentstatus"] == $status)) echo ' selected'?>><?php echo $status; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```